# 403 Forbidden Error Accessing Delegate Mailbox with Office 365 APIs

Tags: ms-office, office365-apps, office365api

I have an app defined in Azure that has permission to read Exchange mailboxes.  I use Azure to get an access code and then access token, and can successfully read messages from the current user's mailbox.  The issue I have is when the current user has delegate rights to a mailbox, this same process results in a 403 Forbidden error rather than the data.  If I open up Outlook I can see the delegate mailbox, it's only when trying to access it via the o365 APIs that it fails.

Once I have my access token I'm asking for the data from this endpoint:  https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/users/mailboxupn@foo.com/messages.  As I say, works fine for getting email from your mailbox, but not for a mailbox to which you have delegate rights.  I've also confirmed that if I log in and get an access token as the owner of the mailbox that has the delegated rights, I'm able to successfully retrieve data.

I've seen a few questions on this (on Matthias' blog) but no answers.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 REST API doesn't support to get the messages as a delegate. You may consider using EWS instead.
Below link maybe helpful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn641963(v=exchg.150).aspx

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Fei.  We're totally committed to o365 APIs so we'll stay the course on it.  Hopefully there is feature parity with EWS in the future.

Comment: Hi Steve,
Based on my understanding, the Office 365 REST API is just providing the service which is atom and stable. The delegate feature belongs to Exchange, however the Office 365 mail service shouldn't know the detail of the mail service provider.
So I don't think the Office 365 REST service is good choose to get the mails for delegates. The Exchange API or EWS is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks Fei, the transparency here though should really be to the developer, not the API.  Clearly the permission connections are in place or it wouldn't work with EWS; they just haven't done the work for feature parity.  MSFT has thrown all their marketing and dev support behind the o365 APIs and I don't see EWS getting anything more than sustained engineering support at this point.  It's just something that needs to be brought up to parity is all.